# Can ssh to raspberry pi and download packages but cant ping any sites

Tags: connection, internet, dns

I am encountering a very odd problem and would greatly appreciate some help.
I can ssh to my RPi and also connect to it via a remote desktop connection.
However, once logged into the RPi I cant ping any sides.
`ping google.com` results in this error: `100% packet loss`

Interestingly, I can still download packages from the internet with the `sudo apt-get`  command without any problems. When I use the remote desktop connection, I can also browse internet pages as if nothing is wrong.

This is the output of `dig google.com`:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1+deb10u8-Raspbian <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 42277
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: 0362fff9060b7d1301000000639a1505077965cf9e311b96 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             93      IN      A       172.217.18.14

;; Query time: 119 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Dec 14 19:25:09 CET 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 83
```

This the output of `traceroute -I www.google.com`:

```
traceroute to www.google.com (172.217.18.4), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  kabelbox (192.168.0.1)  2.574 ms  2.674 ms  2.908 ms
 2  de-mhg01a-rt03.aorta.net (84.116.198.95)  10.849 ms  16.832 ms  16.949 ms
 3  de-mhg01a-ra03-ae-18-0.aorta.net (84.116.190.89)  19.264 ms  19.538 ms  19.536 ms
 4  de-fra04d-rc1-ae-60-0.aorta.net (84.116.191.221)  19.608 ms  19.886 ms  19.783 ms
 5  84.116.190.94 (84.116.190.94)  18.412 ms  18.544 ms  18.769 ms
 6  74.125.48.122 (74.125.48.122)  26.570 ms  24.953 ms  25.033 ms
 7  142.251.65.69 (142.251.65.69)  22.745 ms  20.227 ms  19.672 ms
 8  172.253.66.137 (172.253.66.137)  24.454 ms  24.665 ms  24.839 ms
 9  fra02s19-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.18.4)  24.475 ms  25.828 ms  25.878 ms
```

and this is the output of `ip a`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:48:de:9e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:48:de:9f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.191/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 545397sec preferred_lft 459911sec
    inet6 2a02:8071:284:2080:29f5:3923:2846:b5df/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 545393sec preferred_lft 545393sec
    inet6 2a02:8071:284:2080:d4e1:fc4f:3d6c:1eb/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 86400sec preferred_lft 43200sec
    inet6 fe80::8fe4:8f39:4238:782c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:c4:38:0e:cb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:c4ff:fe38:ecb/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: vethb0a1eee@if5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default
    link/ether 22:b1:dd:1a:19:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet 169.254.213.56/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global noprefixroute vethb0a1eee
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e7e9:75ef:1e75:abc8/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: vethd6760a7@if7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default
    link/ether be:5d:70:30:fe:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 169.254.244.187/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global noprefixroute vethd6760a7
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::b145:157b:8b0a:c3e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

My python scripts which use `urllib3` also get stuck at the

```
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
```

step and I suspect, that this is connected with the "ping" issues that I am observing.

Any insights how to fix this are greatly appreciated!

Comment: what happens if you `traceroute -I www.google.com`

Comment: I made an edit to my original post.

Comment: that's odd ... you can `traceroute -I` but not `ping` - I always thought both used the same underlying protocol

Comment: `ping` uses ICMP whereas `traceroute`, depending on the platform, uses both ICMP and UDP (User Datagram Protocol) data packets to find the packet loss and return time. Ref.: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/traceroute-and-ping/

Comment: Do you have any firewall in your network?